# Uglify node module with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I want to uglify my code to make it smaller and faster. This is a node module and i need to use the classes even when is uglified. Is there a way to do this with webpack or should i use other tools? If there is a way what would be the webpack configuration to achieve this?

Am intending to use this module in vue js and in the backend with express.

This is what i got:

Files:

src

- index.js
- Dog.js

dist

- main.js

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'production',
};
```

index.js

```
const Dog = require("./Dog");
module.exports = {
  Dog
}
```

Dog.js

```
class Dog{
  //Typical Dog stuff
}
module.exports = Dog;
```

anotherFile.js (in the root of the project)

```
//This works
const Dog = require("./src/index").Dog;
//This does'nt works
const Dog2 = require("./dist/main").Dog;

let dog1 = new Dog("Doberman");
let dog2 = new Dog2("Shibainu");
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: You can't export a class that way you should use the es6 method `export class Dog { //stuff}` then `import { Dog } from './Dog.js'` and then use it as you would regularly use a class.

Comment: @Ameer You can export a class that way. ES6 is not mandatory. I don't want to mess with babel in this project as it is an unnecessary complication. But if what you are telling me is that unless i use es6, classes don't work with webpack that's another thing.

Comment: I see, is the issue that you want to access the class from the console then, because you should be able to access the class from any where it gets required

Comment: @Ameer Is just that it does'nt work when i import the class. It works perfectly if is not uglified.

Comment: Can you post the code where you access the class and the error, if you have one, that gets outputted

Comment: @Ameer Posted the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210073/discussion-between-ameer-and-jogarcia).

Comment: Try changing the `.Dog2` to `.Dog` because the class name should stay the sam

Comment: Why are you trying to uglify *server side code*? You say make it smaller which doesn't matter because you aren't sending it over a wire, and you say make it faster which it won't be.

Comment: That was *4 years ago*. That's a long time in Javascriptland. It *will* make your code *parse* faster, which matters on the frontend: you're trying to get to interactive as fast as possible. But it doesn't matter so much on the backend where you amortize your startup cost over the runtime of the application. And you were already uglifying the frontend to save bandwidth. All that being said, you are adding a build step that's going to create friction for very uncertain performance gains that even if present may not be there in 6 months. If perf matters that much use something besides node.

Comment: @JaredSmith you should make that the answer, i made my research and apparently that included outdated articles, i genuinely did'nt knew that, and there must be some others knuckleheads out there (other than me) that would benefit from this information.

Comment: @jogarcia done, let me know if there's anything I need to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't bother uglifying server-side code. You really don't have the bandwidth concerns you would on the frontend.

As for performance, it will make your code parse faster, which matters on the frontend: you're trying to get to interactive as fast as possible. But it doesn't matter so much on the backend where you amortize your startup cost over the runtime of the application. And you were already uglifying the frontend to save bandwidth.

All that being said, you are adding a build step that's going to create friction for very uncertain performance gains that even if present may not be there in 6 months. I'm all for easy optimizations, but if perf matters that much use something faster than node.